# How to list object using delimeter and sort_by in aws s3 api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How to list object using delimeter and sort_by in aws s3 api?

I used below command to list object using delimeter to print second level folder only -

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $bucketNameToUse --prefix $prefixToUse --output text --delimiter "/"
COMMONPREFIXES  firstlevelfolder1/
COMMONPREFIXES  firstlevelfolder2/
```

It worked fine and print second level folders based on prefix that I passed.

And I used below command to list the objects based on last modified date.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $bucketNameToUse --prefix $prefixToUse --output text --query 'sort_by(Contents,&LastModified)[*].[Key,LastModified]'
firstlevelfolder1/  2018-12-28T11:41:07.000Z
firstlevelfolder2/  2018-12-28T11:41:18.000Z
firstlevelfolder1/secondlevelfolder1/   2018-12-28T11:41:30.000Z
firstlevelfolder2/secondlevelfolder2/   2018-12-28T11:41:43.000Z
firstlevelfolder1/secondlevelfolder1/test.java  2018-12-28T11:42:28.000Z
firstlevelfolder2/secondlevelfolder2/test.java  2018-12-28T11:42:46.000Z
```

it worked fine and print the objects sorted by time.

But when I tried to combine both the command I got error -

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $bucketNameToUse --prefix $prefixToUse --output text --query 'sort_by(Contents,&LastModified)[*].[Key,LastModified]' --delimiter "/"

In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array'], received: "null"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of both `delimeter` and `sort_by` by `lastModified` is not possible because the output of `delimeter` doesn't contain anything except object name and when we combine both `delimeter` with `sort_by` function it throws an error as it does not find any content to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is probably returning 0 objects (`None` value here) but the `sort_by` method will expect an array

Check if this returns objects or not: 
`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $bucketNameToUse --prefix $prefixToUse --output text --delimiter "/"`

If this does not then that's your issue.

Comment: Thanks for checking on my question @sanster_23, the command given by you is same which I used in my question and it prints the result and the second command that I used without delimeter also worked fine to sort the objects but when I used `delimiter` and `sort_by` it didn't work.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR when you get only folders in the list that means - you have a list of object prefixes like (f1/, f2/) etc. these do not have a LastModified field. 
only Objects do.

Comment: I have updated my question with output to make it more clear and I can see every level object have lastmodified time.